# Handling failure requests in SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

How to handle failure requests in `SFSafariViewController`? After lot's of research, I came to know that no customization is possible with SFSafariViewController. I'm wondering how to handle failure requests in `SFSafariViewController`?

Want to show an alert and dismiss `SFSafariViewController` when the request fails. Is this possible by any chance? (Not interested in using WKWebview as SFSafariViewController provides more security in case of OAuth)

Thanks

Comment: Use the [safariViewController(_:didCompleteInitialLoad:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontrollerdelegate/1621215-safariviewcontroller) of [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontrollerdelegate).